# Text to Speech not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, text-to-speech

I am simultaneously doing speech to text and text to speech within an app but for some reason after Speech to conversion is over and the result for which is back from server , text to speech [default API of apple] doesn't produce any sound even though it reproduces same for static text at start of app.

Here is the below code for text to speech conversion.

```
-(void)makeTextTalk:(NSString *)phraseToSpeak{
[self stopTalkingAPI];
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc]initWithString:phraseToSpeak];
AVSpeechSynthesisVoice *voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-IN"];
utterance.voice = voice;
[synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[_audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
[_audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:nil];
```

Finally , this solved it.
Session Category must be AVSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord if TTS and STT is continuously working and the function must be called with set options parameter.

Answer (score -1):

U Need to change AVAudioSessionMode to default once Speech To text process gets completed. Change it using this :

```
   AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
   [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback];
   [audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:nil];
```

Comment: Check might be u are missing something.

Comment: I declared audiosession in header file and set it for both. Should the audio session for STT and TTS be separate

Comment: try it with creating separate.

Comment: still no audio.

Comment: Check if ur device is in silent mode?

Comment: nope , first time voice is coming. only second time after STT its not coming.